# ExtJS Multiline data in TreePanel's cell

Tags: extjs, multiline, treepanel

is there a way to utilize treepanel and display multiline data in cell ? I am using column's renderer to format data in `<table>` element (2-3 rows) and display it in cell.

Best regards kkris1983

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just do

```
.x-grid-cell-inner {
    height: auto !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

and it will work perfectly on the embedded table.

Comment: Treecolumn class would have been extended to display properly dot-lines. But anyway I will accept it as a solution. Thank You.